# How to achieve inter region VPC connections using transit gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

AWS doesn't support inter region VPC connections using transit gateway. Is there any way to achieve it using transit gateway and using some other services in AWS?

Comment: VPC supports cross-region connectivity natively with VPC peering, no Transit Gateway needed, so I assume that simply connecting VPCs to each other across regional boundaries is not your objective... in which case I'm unsure what your objective actually is.  Please consider deleting this question from Stack Overflow and re-posting it to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) with additional details of what you are actually trying to accomplish using Transit Gateway.

Comment: Have you seen this? [https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-transit-gateway-supports-inter-region-peering/](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-transit-gateway-supports-inter-region-peering/) It looks like a new feature, Dec/2019, it seems to be supported now.

Answer (score 0):

It is available now via Network manager feature connecting transit gateways together. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/what-is-network-manager.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you kindly provide some context to this answer in order to help the OP? Would be even good to quote the important section of the web page you are linking in case it goes offline for any reason.
You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer